# Dynamodb return all results sorted

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've got a simply dynamodb model:

```
id (partition key), timestamp_id (sort key)
```

All I simply want is to get all the data out of dynamo (using limit and such) but sorted by `timestamp_id`. A scan unfortunately doesn't return sorted data, and it seems I can't have an empty query, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support this use case. If you find yourself in this situation you'll need to store the partition keys in a separate data store and retrieve those first. Then you can issue queries on each key in order and get all your table's data

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you found solution by any chance?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cant get all your records sorted by timestamp_id.

you can get timestamp_id sorted only per 'id'.

dynamodb sort your results by your composite key.

so in your case if your rows looks like:

```
1,3
1,2
2,4
1,5
2,3
```

the results in your case is:

```
1,2
1,3
1,5
2,3
2,4
```

as you see, result are not sorted only by timestamp_id, but id-timestamp_id.

Comment: And what does that query look like?

Comment: It's not a query but a scan and this example incorrectly makes it seem like you would get your items back sorted by key which is not the case. While you can request items to be sorted by range key, you might get 2,3, 2,4 followed by 1,2,13,1,5

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (let's name it `timestamp_id-index`):

We will specify our index's partition key to be an attribute named `fixed_val`, and our sort key to be `timestamp_id-index`.

`fixed_val` will contain any value you want, but it must always be that value, and you must know it from the client side. For the sake of this example, let's say that `fixed_val` will always be `1`.

GSI keys do not have to be unique, so don't worry if there are two duplicated `timestamp_id` values.

You would query the table like this:

```
var now = Date.now();

//...

{
    TableName: "foo",
    IndexName: "timestamp_id-index",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#f": "fixed_value"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":f": 1,
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: "#f = :f",

    // true -> ascending, false -> descending
    ScanIndexForward: true
}
```

Comment: its not good practise to have partition key as a single value. he will get many throughput errors...

Comment: @EyalCh Never said it was a good idea. **Yet**, it is a workaround to his problem without having to redesign the table layout

Comment: That's a terrible idea (to create an index with a single value key), for anything but the most trivial of workloads - in which case you could just scan and sort in memory anyway..